# PHP - Editing multiple array values (if they exist)

Tags: php, arrays

I have a multidimensional array. I need to search it for a specific range of values, edit those values and return the edited data.

Example array:

```
array(3) {
  ["first"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(4) "baz1"
  }
  ["second"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(4) "foo1"
  }
  ["third"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(4) "foo2"
  }
```

Now I want to find any values that match foo (foo1 and foo2 in the example array), insert "-bar" into them (foo-bar1, foo-bar2) and return that value. What are the best ways to approach this?

*EDIT* I should have mentioned that foo could actually be anythingfoo (ex. examplefoo1, somethingelsefoo2, blahblahfoo3). I think this rules out str_replace.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your array will not be extremely deep, this can work.
($array being what you want to replace later with yours)

```
$array= array('first' => array('bazi1'), 'second' => array('foo1'), 'third' => array('foo2') );
function modify_foo(&$item, $key)
{
   $item = str_replace('foo', 'foo-bar', $item);
}
array_walk_recursive( $array, 'modify_foo' );
```

If you want foo to be replaced even in somethingelsefoo2, then str_replace will be just fine.

Answer (score 5):

How about something like this:

```
function addDashBar($arr)
{
    foreach ($arr as $key => $value)
    {
       if (is_array($value))
           $arr[$key] = addDashBar($value)
       else
       {
           $arr[$key] = str_replace($value, "foo", "foo-bar");
       }
    }

    return $arr;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 function test_replace1(&$input, $search, $replace) {
    $result = array();
    $numReplacements = 0;
    foreach ($input as &$value) {
        if (is_array($value)) {
            $result = array_merge($result, test_replace1($value, $search, $replace));
        } else {
            $value = str_replace($search, $replace, $value, $numReplacements);
            if ($numReplacements) {
                $result[] = $value;
            }
        }
    }
    return $result;
 }

 $changed_values = test_replace1($arr, 'foo', 'foo-bar');
```

Comment: This may be an ignorant question but what does the ampersand do when you place it in front of a variable? It's kind of hard to use a search engine to find that answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a 1 dimensional array, you should be able to use array_map();

** Edit: I had some code here but, after testing , it doesn't work.

In regards to your edit.
Just because Foo is at the end of the string, does not mean str_replace will no longer work.

```
echo str_replace("foo","foo-bar","mycrazystringwithfoorightinthemiddleofit");
```

will still return

```
mycrazystringwithfoo-barrightinthemiddleofit
```

if your array is a tree structure of arbitrary depth, then it is unavoidable that you will have to use recursion and the problem becomes non-trivial. You might want to check out the

array_recursive_walk() function. 
[here](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php)
Hope this helps.